# One sided label smoothing in GANs

Tags: deep-learning, statistics, probability, gan

How does one-sided label smoothing make the discriminator more robust by reducing the confidence in correct class?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's start with what label smoothing is. We replace the 0s and 1s in one hot encoding for example for the MNIST dataset with 10 classes by smoothed values e.g.: 0.1 for 1, 0.9 for 9 etc.

If we replace positive classification targets with $\alpha$ and negative targets with $\beta$ the optimal discriminator $D$ becomes:

$$D(x)=\frac{\alpha p_{data}(x) + \beta p_{model}(x)}{p_{data}(x) + p_{model}(x)}$$.

Where the $p_{data}(x)$ corresponds to the original distribution; at least we think. And the $p_{model}(x)$ corresponds to the distribution that we want to target and $x$ are the input features to the discriminator $D$.

Now, when $\beta \neq 0$, erroneous samples from $p_{model}$ have no incentive to move nearer to the data i.e. it reinforces current generator behaviour. Hence, we smooth only the positive labels to $\alpha$, leaving negative labels set to 0. This behaviour prevents discriminator from giving very large gradient signal to the generator.